# Reading and writing XML node

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following XML file:

```
    <MODEM_LIST>
  <MODEM>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <PORT>6</PORT>
    <ENABLED>True</ENABLED>
    <MODE>R</MODE>
    <TARGET_PREFIX>012</TARGET_PREFIX>
  </MODEM>
  <MODEM>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <PORT>42</PORT>
    <ENABLED>False</ENABLED>
    <MODE>B</MODE>
    <TARGET_PREFIX>012</TARGET_PREFIX>
  </MODEM>
</MODEM_LIST>
```

I am able to read 1st modem details with the following VB.Net code:

```
    M1_ID = Module1.Read_XML_Value(sFile, "/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM", "ID")
    M1_PORT = Module1.Read_XML_Value(sFile, "/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM", "PORT")
    M1_ENABLED = Module1.Read_XML_Value(sFile, "/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM", "ENABLED")
    M1_MODE = Module1.Read_XML_Value(sFile, "/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM", "MODE")
    M1_TARGET_PREFIX = Module1.Read_XML_Value(sFile, "/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM", "TARGET_PREFIX")
```

But how can I direct to the 2nd modem? I can't figure out the path

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath index to select, for example, 2nd `<MODEM>` element within a `<MODEM_LIST>` parent :

```
/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM[2]
```

Notice that XPath index starts from `1` instead of `0` as in VB.NET array/list index.

Comment: It's working! But I need to change the first one to 
"1_ID = Module1.Read_XML_Value(sFile, "/xml/SMSConfig/MODEM_LIST/MODEM[1]", "ID")" too.